# Is there any way to make SQL queries like mysql_insert_into("tablename",$arrayofvariables) in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am wondering if there are any frameworks like these.

```
mysql_insert_into("tablename",$arrayofvariables)
```

Comment: You could look into Zend_Db http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html

Comment: I think all the framework can do this. Anyway, the Zend Framework surely allows it.

Comment: where? manual doesnt show anything like this. it has adapter but instead of using that adapter I would write the query myself. framework is not necessarily time saving.

Comment: The question is very ambiguous as written. What exactly is the code sample supposed to do? What's the desired behavior? What's the format of `$arrayofvariables`?

Comment: Inserting the variables into table regardless of the array size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to neatly insert data into a mysql table:

```
<?php
function mysql_insert($table, $inserts) {
    $values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($inserts));
    $keys = array_keys($inserts);

    return mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');
}
?>

For example:

<?php

mysql_insert('cars', array(
    'make' => 'Aston Martin',
    'model' => 'DB9',
    'year' => '2009',
));
?>
```

also there is a library called [dbFacile](http://www.greaterscope.net/projects/dbFacile) which does this exactly, but requires creating a db object.

Answer (score 2):

The sample code and description isn't exactly complete, but if you mean `$arrayofvariables` contains the values to insert as a row, indexed either by position or name, then [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.execute) can take an array:

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` (foo, baz, bam) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ');
$query->execute(array('bar', 42, 'bug-AWWK'));

$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` (foo, baz, bam) VALUES (:foo, :baz, :bam) ');
$query->execute(array(':foo' => 'bar', ':baz' => 42, ':bam' => 'bug-AWWK'));
```

Comment: similar to what I look for but preparing a statement takes longer than the common mysql_query. thank you anyway. maybe there is no method like i meantioned.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: When I tested them, a single `PDO::prepare` and `PDO::execute` or `mysqli::prepare` and `mysqli::execute` took about the same time as `mysql_query`. Executing the same prepared statement multiple times, which is where prepared statements are designed to be more performant, took *less* time than repeatedly executing `mysql_query`. Prepared statements are the proper thing to do when you have a statement with varying data, or when executing a query multiple times. As for what you've mentioned, there's not enough to know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, see e.g. Zend_Db. [This is the relevant documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert). Zend_Db isn't exactly lightweight, though.